# prepared statement already exists

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am obviously missing something.  I am using this sequence to prepare a statement and execute it.

```
$result = pg_prepare($link,"getacctname",'SELECT accounts.acctname FROM accounts WHERE  accounts.acctname = $1') or die(pg_last_error());

$result = pg_execute($link,"getacctname",array($this->valuetofind)) or die(pg_last_error());
```

I always get the error "prepared statement already exists". I have read the other posts and even tried adding before the prepare and same result.

```
pg_query($link, "DEALLOCATE getacctname");
```

I even tried changing the name of the query and rebooting my machine to make sure there was nothing stuck that I was not seeing. same result.

Comment: this link about checking for prepared statement already existing may help: http://www.ask-coder.com/132005/php-check-if-an-pg_prepare-prepared-statement-already-exist.

Comment: This may happen when using a misconfigured connection pooler or permanent connections (pg_pconnect?). The already existing prepared statement is created by a previous execution with the same db connection.

Comment: I would agree that this could be the issue if it were not for my rebooting my machine, just to make sure I had killed all stuck processes, and then did that statement first.  It gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using    pg_query($link, "DEALLOCATE ALL");  before the prepare fixed the problem.

However the troubling issue is that the only place prepare statement was used for that name query name was at that location. After turning off my machine and coming back to puzzle I tried the process that ran the code and it said that the statement already existed even though that was the first time the code was run.